# Mongoose - Update multiple fields in nested array

Tags: arrays, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate, findoneandupdate

I have below object.

```
{
  _id: ObjectId(6082adfaeced28382c167bd7),
  inviteMountaineers:
  [{
    _id: ObjectId(6082c4f9dcfaa86794601058),
    userId: ObjectId(60829eb5f1d2c316dfd79cd8),
    status:"Invited"
  },{
    _id: ObjectId(6082c4f9dcfaa86794601055),
    userId: ObjectId(60829eb5f1d2c316dfd79cd5),
    status:"Invited"
  }]
}
```

> I want to update status of invited mountaineers and I tried using
> below code.

```
 const expedition = await Expedition.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    _id: expeditionId,
    inviteMountaineers: {
      $elemMatch: { userId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId) }
    }
  },
  { useFindAndModify: false },
  { $set: {
            'inviteMountaineers.$.status': status, 
            'inviteMountaineers.$.paidStatus': paidStatus,
            'inviteMountaineers.$.paidAmount': amount, 
          }
  }
).populate({
  path: 'inviteMountaineers',
  populate: {
    path: 'userId',
    model: 'User',
  },
})
```

This code returns the expedition object without any update. No update in the database also. Great if someone could help me with this.

Comment: move this to third parameter `{ useFindAndModify: false }`

Comment: Oh it is working, Database was updated. But still returns the old object. Can you help me with that also. @turivishal

Comment: just pass `new: true` in third parameter options `{ useFindAndModify: false, new: true }`

Comment: Thank you very much. Its working now. :)